# Combining all values of two different columns in a CSV

Tags: python, list

Ok, so I am importing a CSV, and then I want to combine all iterated values in `row[0]` with the iterated values in `row[1]`.

```
csvfile = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',')

for row in csvfile:
    row[0] + row[1]
```

Like that, except I want all of the values of `row[0]` to combine with all of the values of `row[1]`, even if they're not on the same row.

So lets say I have two columns, one column is:

```
asparagus
beets
corn
cucumbers
tomatoes
```

and the other is:

```
pineapple
orange
apple
raspberry
blueberry
```

I want to have asparagus combine with ALL of list 2., i.e.:

```
asparagus pineapple
asparagus orange
asparagus apple
asparagus raspberry
asparagus blueberry
```

And then on to beets pineapple, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: from itertools import product

In [3]: csvfile = csv.reader(open('filename', 'rb'), delimiter=',')

In [4]: list(product(*zip(*list(csvfile))))
Out[4]: 
[('asparagus', 'pineapple'),
 ('asparagus', 'orange'),
 ('asparagus', 'apple'),
 ('asparagus', 'raspberry'),
 ('asparagus', 'blueberry'),
 ('beets', 'pineapple'),
 ('beets', 'orange'),
 ('beets', 'apple'),
 ('beets', 'raspberry'),
 ('beets', 'blueberry'),
 ('corn', 'pineapple'),
 ('corn', 'orange'),
 ('corn', 'apple'),
 ('corn', 'raspberry'),
 ('corn', 'blueberry'),
 ('cucumbers', 'pineapple'),
 ('cucumbers', 'orange'),
 ('cucumbers', 'apple'),
 ('cucumbers', 'raspberry'),
 ('cucumbers', 'blueberry'),
 ('tomatoes', 'pineapple'),
 ('tomatoes', 'orange'),
 ('tomatoes', 'apple'),
 ('tomatoes', 'raspberry'),
 ('tomatoes', 'blueberry')]
```

Comment: Yes, but my format is not in row = [["blah", "blah", "blah"], ["two", "two, "two"]]

Comment: @AndrewAlexander I'm afraid I don't quite understand the problem. Is it that you need to format each pair as a string?

Comment: Well, I still need to iterate over the whole list, don't I?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander To do what? You said you need to "combine" two rows, I showed how to list all combinations. Could you specify your actual goal?

Comment: I am getting this output:w'), ('t', 'e'), ('t', 'b'), ('t', 's'), ('t', 'i'), ('t', 't'), ('t', 'e')]
[('B', 'P'), ('B', 'a'), ('B', 'g'), ('B', 'e'), ('B', ' '), ('B', 'R'), ('B', 'a'), ('B', 'n'), ('B', 'k'), ('B', 'i'), ('B', 'n'), ('B', 'g'), ('2', 'P'), ('2', 'a'), ('2', 'g'), ('2', 'e'), ('2', ' '), ('2', 'R'), ('2', 'a'), ('2', 'n'), ('2', 'k'), ('2', 'i'), ('2', 'n'), ('2', 'g'), ('B', 'P'), ('B', 'a'), ('B', 'g'), ('B', 'e'), ('B', ' '), ('B', 'R'), ('B', 'a'), ('B', 'n'), ('B', 'k'), ('B', 'i'), ('B', 'n'), ('B', 'g')]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]

Comment: my code is as follows: csvfile = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',')
                combinations = []
                
                for row in csvfile:
                    test = list(product(row))
                    print test

Comment: @AndrewAlexander I get it, we used `row` to store different things. See the edited answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't need all that, I figured it out myself. I just created two empty lists for rowa and rowb, and then appended the values to them, before using list(product(rowa, rowb). I'm going to go ahead and say that this was the answer though, because it was about 85% there :)

Comment: @AndrewAlexander I don't get what you mean by "all that", as the problem is essentially solved in one line. Anyway, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
csvfile = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',')

combinations = []

for rowa in csvfile:
    for rowb in csvfile:
        combinations.append(rowa[0] + ' ' + rowb[1])
```

Comment: This will iterate over `rowb` `len(rowa) * len(rowb)` times.

Comment: @Blender the result size is O(n^2), how can the run time is lower than that?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I thought that the OP was looking to combine two rows into one, not to make every possible combination.